# How does one modify the "boot name" of an EFI boot partition?

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning, uefi

I have a USB flash drive with a bootable copy of PassMark MemTest86 set up on it.  When I go to use it on a macOS system, at the boot device selection screen it only shows up as "EFI Boot,"  the standard name given by macOS to any bootable partition that doesn't specify a name.  I'd like to change it so that the thumb drive actually shows up as "MemTest86" on the boot menu.  Can I do that?

Comment: have you tried setting the filesystem's label to what you'd like to see?

Comment: You mean the volume name?  Right now I have it named "2 GB FAT32" and it shows up as "EFI boot."  It seems that for external volumes there's no connection between the volume name and the name shown in the boot menu.

Comment: i think this is what you're looking for: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-can-i-change-the-title-of-a-boot-image (`bless` command)

Comment: @quixotic Good find.  If you post it as an answer I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: nah, i'm just guessing when it comes to osx stuff.  that was a lucky google search, any writeup i made would just be parroting that link.  glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

I have Ubuntu 19.04 installed on USB drive divided into 2 partitions:

- an EFI, which contains /EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI and /EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg;
- an ext4, which contains all others Linux files.

When I press option key on Macbook startup the menu shows a "generic" icon with the label "EFI boot". To customize the icon i put a file called ".VolumeIcon.icns" into root of EFI partition. You can download icns set from [Mac icns](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mac-icns/). To customize the label i use the following command:

```
sudo bless --folder /<DIR_WICH_CONTAINS_BOOTX64.EFI>/ --label "Ubuntu 19.04"
```

For my partition "DIR_WICH_CONTAINS_BOOTX64.EFI" is "/Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/". The command creates two files, ".disk_label" and ".disk_label_2x". The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdmAo.jpg) shows the result.

Comment: For background on the `.disk_label` format, see http://refit.sourceforge.net/info/vollabel.html